# GWT how to make a clickhandler inside my arrayList

Tags: java, gwt

I have this simple `ArrayList`

```
Image img = new Image("/Mobile 005.JPG");
Image img1 = new Image("/Mobile 006.JPG");
Image img2 = new Image("/Mobile 007.JPG");
Image img3 = new Image("/Mobile 008.JPG");
imgList.add(img);
imgList.add(img1);
imgList.add(img2);
imgList.add(img3);

HorizontPanel hpnl = new HorizontalPanel();
hpnl.add(imgList);
```

This list of images will be coming from db and can be of any number.

At this time this `HorizontalPanel` contains 4 images (it may contain 400 images in future), Now if a user comes and click on the second image lets say , how will we know which image has been clicked by the user?

where and how will I put my `clickHandler`?

Answer (score 2):

You will get to know which image is clicked by using the getSource() API as -

```
Image img = new Image("/Mobile 005.JPG");
img.addClickHandler( getClickHandler() ); 
Image img1 = new Image("/Mobile 006.JPG");
img1.addClickHandler( getClickHandler() ); 
Image img2 = new Image("/Mobile 007.JPG");
img2.addClickHandler( getClickHandler() ); 
Image img3 = new Image("/Mobile 008.JPG");
img3.addClickHandler( getClickHandler() ); 
imgList.add(img);
imgList.add(img1);
imgList.add(img2);
imgList.add(img3);

HorizontPanel hpnl = new HorizontalPanel();
hpnl.add(imgList);

ClickHandler imageClickHandler;

private ClickHandler getClickHandler()
{ 
     if( imageClickHandler != null)
     {
          return imageClickHandler;
     }
     imageClickHandler = new ClickHandler()
     {
            public void onClick( ClickEvent event )
            {
              Image source = (Image)event.getSource();
                  // This is the source that has caused the event.
            }
     };

     return imageClickHandler;
}
```

Comment: As a side note for performance i would suggest usage of CellList or CellTable with SelectionModel instead of Horizontal Panel with images. http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList

Comment: thanks , but where and on which image will put this clickHandler, as there will be unknown numbers of images coming from the DB,if you could please put this cickhandler in my code above

Comment: Updated the answer with more code. As @SSR commented i also strongly suggest you to use CellList Widget instead of List of Images With Horizontal panel.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try with following.

```
    HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
    hp.add(getImage("/Mobile 005.JPG"));
    hp.add(getImage("/Mobile 006.JPG"));
    hp.add(getImage("/Mobile 007.JPG"));
    hp.add(getImage("/Mobile 008.JPG"));

    private Image getImage(String imagePath){
    Image image = new Image(imagePath);
    image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
       // write the on click code.
     }
     });

}
```

From the imagepath variable, you can get to know which onclick is called.

Comment: You would be redundantly creating hundreds of anonymous ClickHandlers even though only one is suffcient!!!!!

Comment: @SSR  please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167507/gwt-handlers-is-better-to-have-many-or-a-single-one-is-it-better-to-keep-them .

Comment: @Baadshah - The link you posted in the above comment also suggests to use Single instance :) and i wonder why you suggested SSR to go through that link :)

Answer (score -3):

Are looking for something like this

```
List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
        images.add(new Image());
        images.add(new Image());//Into this list add your DB images list
        images.add(new Image());

        for (Image image : images) {
            image.addClickHandler(
           //singleton instance of clickhandler
            });
        }
```

Comment: You would be redundantly creating hundreds of anonymous ClickHandlers even though only one is suffcient!!!!!

Comment: IMO Without registering the handler you can't get the event.And better to Instead of casting source to Gwt object each time!Well in that case @junai will may get the solution from the both answers.

Comment: The same click handler can be registered to each Image. Reducing the number of dom event handlers is one way Cell widgets function faster and better.

Comment: @SSR Please go through the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167507/gwt-handlers-is-better-to-have-many-or-a-single-one-is-it-better-to-keep-them

Comment: @SSR  I hope you will come to know there is nothing harm by registering many handlers.